# How to plot a graph of expected vs actual values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, charts

**Current Dataframe**

```
          Original      Predicted
0           1059         810.37
1           1441         527.76
2           977          366.07
...
744         2000         1878.18
```

Expected Graph

[image: H<code>enter code here</code>]

Code that I have tried:

```
plt.plot(arr, sub_df['original'], 'b-', label = 'actual')
plt.plot(arr, sub_df['predicted'], 'ro', label = 'prediction')
plt.xticks(rotation = '60'); 
plt.legend()
```

Current Output:

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me. The actual is there, behind the prediction. You can swap the order of the two `plt.plot` and you would see it. The graph says that your model is not working very well, however.

Answer (score 0):

assuming df is your DataFrame:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.Original)
plt.plot(df.Predicted, 'o')

plt.show()
```